# Getting SQL syntax error for criteria ADDDATE function

Tags: java, mysql, criteria, specifications

I'm trying to add a date in the existing Date expression. If I do it, I'm getting **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' programsub0_.subscribed_date)' at line 1**

My Code:

```
Expression<Date> expiryDate = criteriaBuilder.function("ADDDATE", Date.class,
                criteriaBuilder.literal("DAY"),
                programSubscriptionRoot.get("subscriptionPlan").get("duration"),
                programSubscriptionRoot.get("subscribedDate"));
```

In the above code sample, **programSubscriptionRoot.get("subscriptionPlan").get("duration")** will give a number of days in Long.class and **programSubscriptionRoot.get("subscribedDate"))** will give a Date.class.

I had also used, "DATE_ADD", "DATEADD" instead of "ADDDATE". But it doesn't work.

**Please help me in the above query to add days in a subscribed day. Thank you.**

Comment: The syntax for `ADDDATE` is `ADDDATE(date, INTERVAL value addunit)`. Are you sure you are doing that in code?

Comment: Hi @aksappy,

Thanks for your reply...

I had referred to the SQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for methods, and its syntax is the same as you said. But how to implement that in this case? Can you please give me a code snippet for this syntax?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found a solution; I had removed the interval from my code and it works.

`Expression<Date> expiryDate = criteriaBuilder.function("ADDDATE", Date.class, programSubscriptionRoot.get("subscribedDate"),programSubscriptionRoot.get("subscriptionPlan").get("duration"));`

[link_to_mysql_doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)...

Thanks, **@aksappy** for your care. Regards..